# Generic method to upcast protocol implementer to protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to write a method to upcast an object that implements a protocol to its protocol.

For instance, let's assume we have a protocol `Drawable`, and a struct (or class) `Shape` that implements it.

```
protocol Drawable {}
struct Shape: Drawable {}
```

I would like to have a non-failable upcast like:

```
let shape = Shape()
let drawable: Drawable = upcast(shape)
```

My nearest solution so far has been the following. But, I do not know how to specify that `T` implements `U` so the result / the type casting doesn't need to be optional / failable.

```
func upcast<T, U>(object: T) -> U? {
    return object as? U
}
```

So I can do:

```
let shape = Shape()
let drawable: Drawable? = upcast(shape)
```

The point of all this is that I'd like to be able to do this:

```
let shapes = [shape]
let drawables: [Drawable] = shapes
```

Is possible to write a generic method that says `T` implements `U`, being U a protocol?

Comment: Obviously not asking about this solution: let drawables = shapes.map({ $0 as Drawable }) ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
// This is your function
func upcast<T, U>(instance: T) -> U? {
    return instance as? U
}

// This is what you can use to upcast sequence into an array
func flatUpcast<S: SequenceType, T, U where S.Generator.Element == T>(sequence: S) -> [U] {
    return sequence.flatMap() {
        upcast($0)
    }
}

// Playground try-out
protocol Drawable { }

struct Shape: Drawable { }

let shape = Shape()
let shapes = [shape, shape, shape]
let drawables: [Drawable] = flatUpcast(shapes)
```

Comment: Nice one! :-) Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer as alternative way extending SequenceType, so becomes more in the way Apple has "reimplemented map" as "non-higher-order function"

Comment: Is there any way to guarantee upcast method to return a non-optional U? I mean kind of saying T is a protocol and U conforms to that protocol.

Comment: @atxe, can't think of it (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Extending `SequenceType` does the job as well:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func upcast<T, U where Self.Generator.Element == T>() -> [U] {
        return flatMap {$0 as? U}
    }
}
```

Credits to Anton Bronnikov as this is only an alternative way of his solution :)

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ahernandezlopez/ec685f9efcf78d73a33d)

Comment: I agree. This way is more natural.